# One delegation lives across multiple files?

Tags: objective-c, tableview, delegation

I have started coding in Objective-C for several days and I have a question about table view.

This is my declaration in myViewController.h file

```
@interface MainViewController : NSViewController < NSTableViewDataSource, NSTableViewDelegate, NSStreamDelegate>
```

and I have a global variable  `NSMutableArray * messages;` in myViewController.m. I updated this messages in the file

In anotherFile.m I have `extern NSMutableArray * messages;` and I update messages in this file as well.

I need to print messages on the table view, the problem is: I can only print the updates in myViewController.m using [self.tableview reloadData] but not anotherFile.m. How can I fix the problem?

Comment: One shortcut tip `< NSTableViewDataSource, NSTableViewDelegate>` is not required.

Comment: Thanks! I fixed it by using a delegation method.

Answer (score 2):

probably should have an adder and a remover method on MainViewController, that is better than exposing your backing datastore... so something like:

```
-(void)addObjects:(NSSet *)objects
{
    for(id obj in objects)
   {
       [messages addObject:obj];
   }
   [reload data];
}
```

Comment: also if you are interested in bindings, you get most of that for free through KVO and using a NSArrayController.